# Simple Redirect but getting the right code?

Tags: redirect, code

I need to change these links so the dashboard link directs to the forum profile instead of the wordpress admin panel profile can you help?

```
   <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/wp-admin/"><?php _e( 'Dashboard' , 'tie' ) ?> </a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php _e( 'Your Profile' , 'tie' ) ?> </a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Logout' , 'tie' ) ?> </a></li>
        </ul>
```

apparently this guy has done it and it works with this code, however i don't know how to change

```
<li><a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/wp-admin/"><?php _e( 'Dashboard' , 'tie' ) ?> </a></li>
```

to

```
<?php echo bbp_get_user_profile_url( get_current_user_id() ); ?>
```

Comment: When you say you don't know how to change from wp-admin link to bbp-profile URL, do you mean you can't find where the relevant code comes from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know how to change the code so it redirects the dashboard link to the bbp-profile url,

Comment: Where in your website is this code showing? Is it in a menu, or on a page? If you are able to tell me where it shows I might be able to tell you where to look to change it.

Comment: I currently have it open in sublime text 3, It's in a widget which is in the theme-functions.php as a function, Basically i need to change the <li> so that it redirects to the bbp_get user profile using that code if you know what i mean?

Comment: If you are seeing the code exactly as you pasted above, you should simply change the line `<li><a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/wp-admin/"><?php _e( 'Dashboard' , 'tie' ) ?> </a></li>` to `<?php echo bbp_get_user_profile_url( get_current_user_id() ); ?>`

Comment: That just leaves a blank area and the dashboard link goes disappears can we somehow make it echo the dashboard so its a clickable link?

Comment: I think maybe I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, or where in your site this code is being called. Could you edit your question for clarity, and add a screenshot or two of the code involved?

Comment: Thanks for the help Strap hopefully this helps

This is the code i need to edit 
http://www.Space-Champion.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/2.png

I simply want to redirect the dashboard link to the forum press forum url using <?php echo bbp_get_user_profile_url( get_current_user_id() ); ?>

http://www.Space-Champion.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/3.png

If i use <?php echo bbp_get_user_profile_url( get_current_user_id() ); ?> the dashboard link disappears completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 1323 of your screenshot with the following:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo bbp_get_user_profile_url( get_current_user_id() );?>">Your Profile</a></li>
```

You can change "Your Profile" with different text if you like.

Comment: That worked beautifully thank you very much Strap1 :)

Comment: No worries! Glad to help.